# How to give value to a drop down calendar using selenium and python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium and i am building this code where i have to give a certain value to the drop down calendar, and i am totally confused.

Below is the html code for the website calendar i am trying to use.
Do help.

```
 <input id="reportDate" name="criteria.reportDate" value="30-Nov-2015" class="form-control datepicker-control form-date" type="text">
```

This is the code i used so far

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('url')

driver.find_element_by_id('reportData').click()
```

i am not sure as to how to proceed after this.

i already wrote the code to get the date value in "30-Nov-2015" format which is in the variable "date".

Sorry if the code is too small to work on, totally new to this.

Comment: This is quite difficult issue to pick exact date from datepicker. I know that `jquery` requests can resolve it, but really I don't know how:) If there is a possibility to just send date to input field instead of select from drop-down- better use it)

Comment: I am looking to do the same thing. Instead of picking a date, i want to give the value like you said, But i am not sure as to how to send the value as an input. I already wrote the code which generates the value in the required format i.e "date-Month-year"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
date = '30-Nov-2015'
driver.find_element_by_id("reportDate").send_keys(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have to select the date from the dropdown calender, you can use Select class for that.

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('url')
select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id("reportData"))
select.select_by_visible_text("30-Nov-2015")
```

you can also use -

```
select.select_by_value("30-Nov-2015")
```

You can see the WebDriver API bindings in Python here:

http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html

The Select() class is at section 7.12. UI Support

Comment: Hello igniteram1, Thanks for the quick help, i tried executing your code and it throws me the following error --> Select cal = new Select(driver.find_element_by_id('reportData');
             ^ Invalid syntax

Comment: @igniteram1, are you sure that your code written on Python?:)

Comment: sorry my bad i wrote in java. This is for python